# How to cancel background noise while playing PCM Audio in STM32?

Tags: c++, stm32, platformio

I am trying to play Audio from PCM data in STM32(blackpill_f411ce). I can hear the audio but there is a steep noise also coming with the audio. I am working in PlatformIO with Audrino's framework.
The PCM data is defined inside the code as an unsigned char array like below

```
unsigned char sample[98216] = {0x52, 0x49, 0x46, 0x46, 0xA0,......}
```

My code is below

```
#include<Arduino.h>
#include <SoundData.h>

#define OUT_PIN_STM_32 PA8
int SineValues[256];    

void InitSineValues()
{
    float ConversionFactor=(2.0*3.142)/256.0;                                           
    float RadAngle;                                     
    for(int MyAngle=0;MyAngle<256;MyAngle++)
   {
        RadAngle=MyAngle*ConversionFactor;              
        SineValues[MyAngle]=(sin(RadAngle)*127)+128;                                            
    }
}

void playPcmData()
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 98216; i++)
  {
    int val=int(sample[i]);
    analogWrite(OUT_PIN_STM_32,SineValues[val]);
    delayMicroseconds(50);

  }
  
}
void setup() {
  InitSineValues();
  
}
void loop() {
  playPcmData();
  delay(5000);
}
```

I used the same code with dacWrite in ESP32 and it works fine.

Comment: if you use delay it will never work :). Learn how to use DMA

Comment: @0___________ It is great if you can share a sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In setup, I added analogWriteFrequency(200000) and the problem solved

```
void setup() {
  analogWriteFrequency(200000);
}
```

And also no need to put sine values

```
void playPcmData()
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 98216; i++)
  {
    int val=int(sample[i]);
    analogWrite(OUT_PIN_STM_32,val);
    delayMicroseconds(50);

  }
}
```